# Float image right of text, but have image move under text on small screen

Tags: css, css-float

I would like to float an image to the right of some text which I've been able to do so far.  But on small screens, I want the image to go below the text but I can't figure out a way to make the image come after the text.

```
<div style="float:left;width:1px;"></div>
<div style="float:right;width:159px;margin-left:25px;">
    <img src="http://apps.weber.edu/wsuimages/academicsoftware/images/projects.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cxm2hsuz/

Comment: Google "responsive design". You can set breakpoints via CSS and create different rules based on the viewport size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a width for your elements, float both left and then if there is not enough space for the image, it will be displayed below your text.

**SNIPPET**

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
}
.text,
.image {
  float: left;
}
.text {
  width: 70%;
}
.image {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://apps.weber.edu/wsuimages/academicsoftware/images/projects.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rb7mzwk6/)**

**EDIT**

Or even better, as @j08691 already mentioned, use responsive webdesign and work with `@media` breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Change the elements order and give them a display block and width. Then use media queries to match small screen resolutions (make it responsive).
Also, you can make the image div style position relative and try with top/left (in px for example) attribute to place it where you want.

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="c" style="
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="b" style="
    float: right;">
    <img src="http://apps.weber.edu/wsuimages/academicsoftware/images/projects.jpg" />
</div>
```